# ios app crash on startup

Tags: ios, crash, crashlytics

I started using crashlytics for my iphone app, and it seems that it crashes for some users during startup (or what I am guessing is startup). Here is the stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19687eba0
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001854aa59c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000195bfc0e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001854b1664 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001854ae418 ___forwarding___ + 928
4  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001853b2b6c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5  UIKit                          0x0000000189fc38a0 -[UILabel _contentInsetsFromFonts] +    104
6  UIKit                          0x000000018a13ac90 -[_UILabelLayer updateContentInsets] + 76
7  UIKit                          0x000000018a13ad50 -[_UILabelLayer updateContentLayerSize] + 56
8  UIKit                          0x000000018a13ae34 -[_UILabelLayer layoutSublayers] + 36
9  QuartzCore                     0x00000001895ac564    CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 320
10 QuartzCore                     0x00000001895ac408 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
11 QuartzCore                     0x00000001895abc08 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 276
12 QuartzCore                     0x00000001895ab98c CA::Transaction::commit() + 436
13 QuartzCore                     0x00000001895a53bc CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
14 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185462a50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
15 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018545f9dc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
16 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018545fdbc __CFRunLoopRun + 836
17 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018538d0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
18 GraphicsServices               0x000000018e52f5a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
19 UIKit                          0x0000000189cc23c0 UIApplicationMain + 1488
20 partybutton                    0x00000001000d6de0 main (main.m:16)
21 libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019626aa08 start + 4
```

Not really sure how to debug this since I cannot reproduce on my own. Any pointers?

Comment: The NSNull is interesting. Does your code ever actually use NSNull for anything?

Comment: I use it simply for comparison purposes in my app. I notice that google analytics does do some stuff with NsNull but I just noticed that from a quick grep...didn't do a deep dive into it.

Comment: Well, it looks vaguely like you're getting a crash because a font is being represented by NSNull. Do you use weird fonts that might not be on the user's device? Do you make some initial attributed strings that go into labels? And now we've reached the end of my guesswork! :)

Comment: Interesting thoughts. I'm not sure where to even start looking because no view controller is indicated in the stack trace. Do you know why that is the case?

Comment: Because it's doing layout. As you can see, it's the transaction commit (what I call in my book the "redraw moment"). That takes place independently after all your code has finished running. That's why you don't see any of your code.

Comment: It's not that easy. I did a grep for that function call already, with no results. No, I didn't post on iphoneDevSdk.

Comment: Check also that any third party API you have used not cause this issue.

Comment: One thing to check if you are getting JSON-data from a server and setting it directly to the text of a UILabel. You assume it is an `NSString`, but for some users the server sends `null` in that field. So the JSON parser creates an `NSNull` and you see the specified behaviour.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I suspect this is the case. Just hard to pinpoint where to look with no clues as to which view controller the crash occurs on.

Comment: Finally was able to repro the crash on my own and it was exactly the suggestion Mats made. Mats if you would like to post your comment as an answer, I will happily mark it as the accepted solution! Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have similar kind of problem. JSON response from sever contains NULL/null. Something like this:

```
"result":[
    {
        "id":"44",
        "message":null,
    }]
```

I created a category of `NSNull` class. Then added the methods of `NSString` that causing the exceptions.

NSNull+JSON.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NSNull(JSON)

@end
```

NSNull+JSON.m file:

```
@implementation NSNull (JSON)

- (NSUInteger)length { return 0; }

- (NSInteger)integerValue { return 0; };

- (float)floatValue { return 0; };

- (NSString *)description { return @"0(NSNull)"; }

- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator { return @[]; }

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key { return nil; }

- (BOOL)boolValue { return NO; }

- (NSRange)rangeOfCharacterFromSet:(NSCharacterSet *)aSet{
    NSRange nullRange = {NSNotFound, 0};
    return nullRange;
}

//add methods of NSString if needed

@end
```

By doing this I do not have to check NULL in every variable.

Comment: awesome. .it saved my day. .thumbs up.

Comment: I had created this class but don't able to understand how can i use this?

Comment: @ios developer : After writing the class your crash for null should be solved. you will get objective c friendly nil. which will not cause your app crash. hope this help

Comment: it's still crash my app.

Comment: [NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: After adding above code correctly you should not get that error. Check your category class implementation.

Answer (score 2):

For my case,it is JSON data reseponed from service contain NULL String,and Json parsing treat it as string,but the iOS system doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

kazi.munshimun, you can use a NSDictionary extension class for doing so. It will automatically check for NULL fields.

[GitHub: NSDictionary extension class](https://github.com/PabloAlejandro/NSDictionary-Utils)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `[NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]` error was related to an empty **User Defined Runtime Attributed** which one of my view controllers needed to work with a third party custom Navigation Controller

Answer (score 0):

IOS does not consider NULL as nil and at run time it crashes..
To overcome this problem just simply compare your json string to NSNULL and then assign to string variable

NSString *yourVariable = ([stringVariable isEqual:[NSNull null]]) ? @"" : stringVariable;

Answer (score 0):

simple way is to check with 
    `NSString *city= set value from json ;`
  for example

then make a check -->

```
NSString *city=[responseDictionaryForEachRow     valueForKey:@"City"];
if (![city isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
    @"Your code if string is not null";`
}
```

Comment: What exactly has this to do with the question?